# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje de error más inteligible al comparar fechas de moment.js con Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, momentjs

Estoy usando [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) para manejar fechas desde JavaScript y [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io) para escribir pruebas unitarias. En un momento dado quiero hacer un test que compruebe que dos fechas son iguales, para lo cual hago lo siguiente:

```
it('properly compares dates', function () {
    var date1 = moment("2000-01-02", "YYYY-MM-DD");
    var date2 = moment("1999-03-04", "YYYY-MM-DD");
    expect(date1).toEqual(date2);
});
```

Esto funciona como se espera: si las fechas fueran iguales el test pasaría, pero como no lo son, pues no pasa. **El problema**: el mensaje de error que lanza contiene el objeto completo, del cual es muy difícil extraer los valores comparados:

> Expected Moment({ _isAMomentObject: true, _i: '2000-01-02', _f:
>   'YYYY-MM-DD', _isUTC: false, _pf: Object({ empty: false, unusedTokens:
>   [  ], unusedInput: [  ], overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, nullInput:
>   false, invalidMonth: null, invalidFormat: false, userInvalidated:
>   false, iso: false }), _locale: Locale({ _ordinalParse:
>   /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: Function, _abbr: 'en',
>   _ordinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ }), _d: Date(Sun Jan 02 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)) }) to equal
>   Moment({ _isAMomentObject: true, _i: '1999-03-04', _f: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
>   _isUTC: false, _pf: Object({ empty: false, unusedTokens: [  ], unusedInput: [  ], overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, nullInput: false,
>   invalidMonth: null, invalidFormat: false, userInvalidated: false, iso:
>   false }), _locale: Locale({ _ordinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
>   ordinal: Function, _abbr: 'en', _ordinalParseLenient:
>   /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ }), _d: Date(Thu Mar 04 1999 00:00:00
>   GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)) })

Mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de personalizar los mensajes de error para los tests fallidos en Jasmine (específicamente para moment.js)? No he podido encontrar ninguna solución en la documentación oficial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He acabado implementando un [custom matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_matcher.html) que registro antes de los tests:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    var customMatchers = {
        toBeSameDate: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    var result = {};
                    result.pass = actual.isSame(expected);
                    result.message = 
                        "Expected " + actual.format("YYYY-MM-DD") +
                        " to equal " + expected.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
});
```

Así pues, simplemente sustituyendo `.toEqual` por `.toBeSameDate` en el test, el mensaje de error cambia a:

> Expected 2000-01-02 to equal 1999-03-04

Esto además tiene la ventaja de que en el futuro puedo extender el matcher si es necesario, por ejemplo para ignorar la hora.

Comment: Ojo! Si la diferencia esta en la hora, los min, seg o ms, esta solución muestra un mensaje confuso.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo comparando la fecha formateada, utilizando [`moment.format()`](http://momentjs.com/#format-dates):

```
var actual   = moment('2015-11-06'),
    esperado = moment('1998-04-09');

expect(actual.format()).toBe(esperado.format());
```

> Expected '2015-11-06T00:00:00-03:00' to be '1998-04-09T00:00:00-03:00'.

Esto de te permite verificar una fecha y si la prueba falla, ver un detalle compacto y completo.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/w5duncaL/

Comment: Buena idea,+1. Pero voy a usar el custom matcher, hace los tests más legibles y como he dicho lo puedo personalizar en el futuro si es necesario.